# Composing an order-dependent Observable chain with multiple async actions

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to compose a chain of observables in an Angular application, and struggling to find the order of operations to make it work as needed. Any insights / pointers on how to implement this would be most appreciated.

I'm particularly interested in the right sequence of operators to make the existing code structure work in the desired order, without extensive refactoring.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve (in description, then pseudocode, then a simplified version of my code, since it is spread across several services):

**description**

Each of the following steps is an observable, with the first being the point where `subscribe()` is called.

1: On successful login, initialize a user service. This is an observable, which is subscribed immediately.

2: Inside this initialization, check if content is stale: fetch a remote JSON file and compare a value there with one stored locally. If they differ (content is stale), flush content cache.

3: After the content check, call two additional services to get JSON files - first by looking for them in cache, then via fetching from a remote server.

Order is important between steps 2 and 3 - step 2 must complete before step 3 starts. Order is unimportant for the service calls in step 3.

If I were logging each step, I'd want to see something like this if content is stale:

```
logon success, initializing user
content is stale, flushing cached content
flushing cached content complete
fetching content
fetching domain
domain fetch complete
content fetch complete
```

and  if content is not stale:

```
logon success, initializing user
content is not stale
fetching content
fetching domain
content fetch complete
domain fetch complete
```

**pseudocode**

```
logon
    on success, (initialize user with logon response)$.subscribe()


(initialize user with logon response)$
    // other stuff happens ... 

    return (fetch remote file and act on content)$ 
        then 
            (get content file foo)$, (get content file bar)$


(fetch remote file and act on content)$ 
    if content is stale 
        return (flush cached content)$
    else 
        return (empty observable)$


(get content file xxx)$
    if file is in cache
        return (retrieve file from cache)$
    else 
        return (fetch remote file)$
```

**simplified code**

```
// login-view.component.ts 
loginClick() {
    this.logonUserService
        .logon(credentials)
        .subscribe((logonResponse) => this.userService.initialize(logonResponse).subscribe());
}

// user.service.ts
initialize(logonResponse) {
    // do stuff with logonResponse, then... 

    return this.checkContentFreshnessService.initialize()
        .pipe(switchMap(() => forkJoin(
            this.contentService.initialize(),
            this.domainService.initialize()
        ));
}

// check-content-freshness.service.ts 
initialize(): Observable<any> {
    return this.contentService.getPublishSummary().pipe(
        tap(
            publishSummary => {
                const isContentStale = publishSummary.changesetId === this.contentService.changesetId;

                return iif(
                    () => isContentStale,
                    this.contentService.flushCache(),
                    of(true)
                );
            }
        )
    );
}

// content.service.ts & domain.service.ts are both essentially
initialize(): Observable<any> {
    const path = this.contentService.getContentPath(contentId);
    // or: const path = this.contentService.getDomainPath();

    return this.contentService.get(path).pipe(
        tap(response => { /* do something locally with response */ }
    );
}
```

Comment: Well in short you should not use side-effects (`tap`, `subscribe`) in your services, and then streams can be composed in order using `concat`/`concatMap` operators

Comment: @OlesSavluk I'm not sure I follow you. I thought that `tap` was supposed to have no effect on the observable output. Also, saying "you should not do x" doesn't help as much saying "you should do y, and here's the reason for it."